# Есть ли какая-нибудь альтернатива свойству CSS `box-shadow` в PyQt5?

Tags: python, css, pyqt5, qss, qgraphicsdropshadoweffect

Подскажите как сделать **`тень у кнопки`** на PyQt5.

**`CSS`**-свойство **`box-shadow`** позволяет добавлять элементу одну или несколько теней, указывая их параметры через запятую.

Свойство тени представляет собой описанные смещения по **`x`** и **`y`** от элемента, радиус размытия и его радиус, а также цвет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`Qt StyleSheet`** - это не **`CSS`**, но это технология, реализующая некоторые функции, среди которых нет **`box-shadow`**.

Если вы хотите реализовать что-то подобное,
вам следует использовать `QGraphicsDropShadowEffect`.

Класс `QGraphicsDropShadowEffect` обеспечивает эффект тени. 
Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsdropshadoweffect.html

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.btn = QPushButton("Button")
        self.combo = QComboBox()

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        layout.addWidget(self.combo)

        for children in self.findChildren(QWidget):
            shadow = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(blurRadius=5, xOffset=3, yOffset=3)
            children.setGraphicsEffect(shadow)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> А подскажите как применить только к одному элементу QPushButton?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.btn = QPushButton("Button")
        self.combo = QComboBox()

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        layout.addWidget(self.combo)

#        for children in self.findChildren(QWidget):
#            shadow = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(blurRadius=5, xOffset=3, yOffset=3)
#            children.setGraphicsEffect(shadow)

        shadow = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(blurRadius=5, xOffset=3, yOffset=3)
        self.btn.setGraphicsEffect(shadow)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А подскажите как применить только к одной кнопке, даже если их много в окне, нужна только одна?

Comment: Можно пожалуйста последний вопрос, где можно подробнее почитать про такие эффекты?

Comment: @Tesla я добавил обновление в свой ответ, проверьте.